# Change font size with animation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I would like to change font size of HTML element using css animation, at the same time when I making that element to shake.

My code:

```
function setZeroScore(){
var score = document.querySelector('#current-'+activePlayer);    
score.animate([
    // keyframes
    { transform: 'translate(1px, 1px)' },
    { transform: 'translate(-1px, -2px)'},
    { transform: 'translate(-3px, 0px)' },
    { transform: 'translate(3px, 2px)' },
    { transform: 'translate(1px, -1px)' },
    { transform: 'translate(-1px, 2px)' },
    { transform: 'translate(-3px, 1px)' },
    { transform: 'translate(3px, 1px)' },
    { transform: 'translate(-1px, -1px)' },
    { transform: 'translate(1px, 2px)' },
    { transform: 'translate(1px, -2px)' }   
  ], { 
    // timing options
    duration: 750,
  });     
}
```

Its works fine for the shaking, but when I tried this I getting error:

```
function setZeroScore(){
var score = document.querySelector('#current-'+activePlayer);
score.animate([
    // keyframes
    { transform: 'translate(1px, 1px)', font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(-1px, -2px)', font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(-3px, 0px)' , font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(3px, 2px)' , font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(1px, -1px)' , font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(-1px, 2px)' , font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(-3px, 1px)' , font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(3px, 1px)' , font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(-1px, -1px)' , font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(1px, 2px)' , font-size:25px },
    { transform: 'translate(1px, -2px)' , font-size:25px }         
  ], { 
    // timing options
    duration: 750,
  });      
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem complete - What is the error?, what is `activePlayer`

Comment: Ignore the active player

Comment: @חייםחדד For future reference, do include the error message that you've received. If you know what they mean they can be pretty good indicators on where to look in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `font-size` is not a valid name for a property.  The dash (`-`) also functions as a [subtraction operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction) and reads the name of your property as: `font - size`. However making the property name a string would make it valid (`'font-size':`), although it would not be recognized as the font size of the element.

JavaScript uses camelCases for such names.
Also `25px` should be a string.

```
{ transform: 'translate(1px, 1px)', fontSize: '25px' },
```